# Unable to show image in recyclerView using glide

Tags: android, android-glide

images are not showing in recycler view.

i am using glide to show images in recycler view

i have a list of images url and passing that list in adapter. very similar method i used in another activity it worked there... but its not working in this activity.

**AnimeActivity.java**

```
public class AnimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView rv;
List<String> adsImagesData  = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anime);
    rv = findViewById(R.id.ads_recyclerview);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    getSupportActionBar().hide();

     adsImagesData.add("http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/62b7af36-65b7-41aa-8db2-e34fd8a76acf/62c5efd3-fa55-464b-8ee5-9a3e2543c830.jpg");

     rv.setAdapter(new AdRecyclerViewAdapter(this , adsImagesData));

}
}
```

**AdRecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class AdRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<String> mData;

public AdRecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_row_item , parent , false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Glide.with(holder.adImg.getContext()).load(mData.get(position)).into(holder.adImg);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView adImg;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        adImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_image_view);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: for test case use https. `adsImagesData.add("https://`

Comment: Did, but still not working. Used another url but still.. is my codes are perfect ?

Comment: `@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }`

Comment: Did this ,, still problem exists

Comment: `RequestManager requestManager = Glide.with(mContext);
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = requestManager.load(mData.get(position));
        requestBuilder.into(holder.adImg);`

Comment: where to implement this

Comment: here `Glide.with(holder.adImg.getContext()).load(mData.get(position)).into(holder.adImg);`

Comment: you mean replace this `Glide.with(holder.adImg.getContext()).load(mData.get(position)).into(holder.adImg);`
 with your answer

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yup it worked.. thanks.. put it in the answer. i'll verify this. can you please explain this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
RequestManager requestManager = Glide.with(mContext); 
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = requestManager.load(mData.get(position));         
requestBuilder.into(holder.adImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and try to use picasso & glide, same result as you describe but when I add one another url in the list, other image successfully showed in recyclerview as

```
    adsImagesData.add("http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/62b7af36-65b7-41aa-8db2-e34fd8a76acf/62c5efd3-fa55-464b-8ee5-9a3e2543c830.jpg");
    adsImagesData.add("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Kf1Bc7wkQtEkbdinSLJhGBNwIjm7R_fe4unmPXHO7bMwg_zArmRhgenhs7nNhb5pp6KJ=s180-rw");
```

when first image is going to download with glide it through error as

```
E/Glide: GlideExceptioncom.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There was 1 cause:
java.io.IOException(Cleartext HTTP traffic to cdn.playbuzz.com not permitted)
```

it means this website not allow to download image in this manner

I check this error by this method

```
Glide.with(holder.adImg.getContext())
 .load(mData.get(position))
 .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
     @Override
     public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
         Log.e("Glide", "GlideException"+e);
         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

         return false;
     }
 })
 .into(holder.adImg);
```

you have to use this method for this

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

add this line in application tag of your manifest file
create layout in resources in xml directory as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
           <domain includeSubdomains="true">cdn.playbuzz.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.
[check this link](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

After this both images are shown in recyclerview as you want

Comment: But i checked it with different urls.. and when i implemented @IntelliJ Amiya code. Even that image(which is in question) was showing in the recyclerview

Comment: check on android 10

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem, and I just change my url from `http` to `https`, here's the example in Java:

```
String url = "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/151.png";
String newUrl = url.substring(0, 4) + "s" + url.substring(4);
Glide.with(context).load(newUrl).into(holder.imageView);
```